# Change title position when using AppBarLayout/Toolbar

Tags: android

How can I set the title position (remove default left margin) when using AppBarLayout/Toolbar?

Here is the current code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="380dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/appbar_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:src="@drawable/scan_bg"
                tools:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="none"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `textview` inside `toolbar` and set text of that `textview`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="none"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/title
    />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: It still leaves a gap on the left if use `layout:gravity="left"`

Comment: use contentInsetLeft property
follow this reference https://learnpainless.com/android/remove-extra-margins-from-toolbar-custom-layout-android

Comment: How can I stop it from duplicating the title when I run the app?

Comment: getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);

Comment: It works the way you suggested, but I did it different. I changed the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` atributes (like `app:expandedTitleMarginBottom`). But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `app:titleEnabled = "false"` to `CollapsingToolbarLayout xml`. Now you can set a title for the `Toolbar` with:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    app:titleEnabled="false"/>
```